# javascript & json, how to process?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json like this:

```
var json = {
  "A": {
    "A1": {
      "A11": "A",
      "A12": "B",
      "A13": "C"
    },
    "A2": {
      "A21": "A",
      "A22": "B",
      "A23": "C"
    }
  },
  "B": {
    "B1": {
      "B11": "A",
      "B12": "B",
      "B13": "C"
    },
    "B2": {
      "B21": "A",
      "B22": "B",
      "B23": "C"
    }
  }
}
```

I can access it using:

```
json.B.B13
```

But I want to loop through all objects. (A, B)
how can I do this?

tought about using for(...)
and:
json[0].B13 but that doesn't work.

How can I do it?

Comment: `Object.entries(json).forEach(([k, v]) => cosole.log(k, v))`

Comment: This is not JSON. This is a JavaScript object.

Comment: You can create a recursive function and process the keys and values based on your requirement: `function process(o) { for(const k in o) { console.log(k, o[k]); if(typeof o[k] === 'object') process(o[k]) } }`

Comment: Thanks. It indeed is a json object out of visual studio.

Comment: @phusi yeah and `JSON` is abbreviation of `JavaScript Object Notation`.

Comment: @ulou `var json =` is not allowed in JSON. The right side of the assignment is a JavaScript object, not JSON data. JSON data is a text/string. You would have to `JSON.parse` JSON data to use it in JavaScript.

Comment: The only _"json object"_ in JavaScript is [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) and it's not what you think.

Comment: @jabaa Your comment kinda makes no sens, `var = json` is `object`/`string` declaration not `JSON` itself. If OP would named it `parsedJson` instead of `json` everything would ok, but let's leave this pointless discussion.

Comment: @ulou My point is that phuzi is right. There is no JSON in this question. There is a JavaScript code that contains a section that would be valid JSON. `var json = JSON.parse('{}')` contains two characters of JSON data. `var json = {}` doesn't contain JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion, `console.log` only if `value` isn't `object`, otherwise repeat:

```js
const json = {A:{A1:{A11:"A",A12:"B",A13:"C"},A2:{A21:"A",A22:"B",A23:"C"}},B:{B1:{B11:"A",B12:"B",B13:"C"},B2:{B21:"A",B22:"B",B23:"C"}}};

const deepIterate = ([k, v]) => {
  if (typeof v === 'object' && v !== null)
    Object.entries(v).forEach(deepIterate)
  else
    console.log(k, v)
}

Object.entries(json).forEach(deepIterate)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore this */
```